# How comes Play!'s compiler acts recursively in some cases?

Tags: java, playframework, compilation, playframework-2.0

Sometimes my compiler starts compiling a bunch of files : 
[info] Compiling 61 Java sources to project\target\scala-2.10\classes...

Then restart compiling the whole project :
[info] Compiling 231 Scala sources and 188 Java sources to project\target\scala-2.10\classes...

Then start again compiling the first bunch of files :
[info] Compiling 61 Java sources to project\target\scala-2.10\classes...

It also happened that the compilation restarts suddenly while the app was initializing (after the compilation phase)...

I have to wait for a while, the compiler makes 2 or 3 cycle, to finally end normally, any clue about this ? I find play's compiler very slow and inefficient when dealing with hundreds of files...

Comment: What version of Play are you using? And more importantly, what sbt version?

Comment: I use Play 2.1.5 with Java 1.7.0_71 and Scala 2.10.0. sbt plugin 2.1.5

Comment: That's what I thought. Upgrading to a later version of Play and sbt will resolve the issue.

Comment: Upgrading my version of Play could issue some backward compatibility, do you think only upgrading sbt plugin could do the job ?

Comment: If you can upgrade to 0.13.5, or better 0.13.7, that should help already with compilation times.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't 0.13.5 older than 2.1.5 ?

Comment: sbt itself is currently at 0.13.7. 2.1.5 refers to Play, which is an sbt plugin.